# How to create a compact longtable which span across multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn, setspace

I trying to create a compact literature review table, which takes up more number of rows page. I am ok with smaller font size than the current version. The output is very spare as shown in the attachment.

Looking forward to your kind suggestions and help with the code.

Thanks and Regards,
Arjun

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cases}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}
\usepackage[numbers,super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont}
\usepackage{appendix}
%\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{ Various research efforts to improve the design of Mixing tank}
\label{Tab:CycloneDesignChanges}
\hline

 \centering
    %\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
        Article &   Target Part & Design Modification & $S_{50}$ Range(\micron) &Summary of Findings\\\hline
        
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Design changes on a mixing tank to function as a Particle Separator($D_{50}$ \leq 3\micron)}                                         \\ \hline
        
        \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{Arjun Kumar Pukkella(2018)}& Inlet section &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Baffle Plate design}& 0.45-0.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{Controlled the cut point by adjusting the guide plate location to alter the inlet clearance  }\\\hline

        \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{yoshida2005}(2005) \cite{yoshida2005}}& Inlet section &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Secondary injection flow}& 0.7-1.25 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{The secondary injection flow should be in the proximity of upper plate and the injection velocity should be a maximum. High tangential velocities are reported in the region close to the secondary injection flow.}\\\hline
        
        \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline

      \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
    \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}}& Inlet section  &\multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{Compressed air injection. Secondary flow} & 1.1-1.75 &
        \multicolumn{1}{m{5cm}|}{It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.}\\\hline
        
        
        
   % \end{tabular}
\end{longtable}
```

[image: In the current output the table looks very spared and only printing three rows per page. I looking for a more compact literature review tables]

Comment: you shouldn't need all those`\multicolumn{1}`. Also your line spacing looks weirdly large but as you have not shown an example that produces the output shown it is hard to comment. please always post examples as complete but minimal test documents. Presumably you have specified double (or more than double) spacing somewhere in code you have not shown)

Comment: Although the table can be improved by changing the font size, line spacing, column width, etc., the important question is if a table is the appropriate format to show the information, at least with this design in  portrait pages. I will consider use lists, for example. On the other hand, use `--`  (en dash) for the ranges.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: \multicolumn{1}{m{2cm}} is needed to constrain the the text in the first column, else it prints the whole text in the cell as a single line. 
I have modified the code by adding the packages required. I request you to kindly provide some help.

Comment: Just use an m type colum instead if a c type column for your first column and you can remove all multicolumn commands, there. The same also applies to the third and last columns on f your table.

Comment: @user3454353 no you only need the occasional multicolumn{1} to over-ride the column spec in a header, there is never a need to use it in every cell. Just specify the column type you want in the argument to tabular. You get a single line if you specify `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document example has many serious flaws. Between them the double spacing of text in table is the minor problem:

- document begin with two `\documentclass`, what lead to error in compilation
- missed are `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`
- in preamble are some packages loaded two times, also with different options
- as it is already mentioned in comments, all `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` are surplus
- defined different widths of cells by `\multicolumns`  in the same column is nonsens, column width is always adopted to the widest widths of cells.
- your document may have to be double spaced, bit if in this you like to have single spaced text in table, you only need to insert in group with table before it the command `\singlespace`.

A possible solution can serve the following MWE. In it are added table headers for each page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}   % <---
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, longtable, makecell,  multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, breqn}
\usepackage[toc,page,header]{appendix}
\usepackage[numbers,super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum} %new, for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\begingroup
    \singlespacing
    \small
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{|L{32mm}|L{22mm}|L{22mm}|L{21mm}|L{55mm}|}
    \caption{ Various research efforts to improve the design of Mixing tank}
    \label{Tab:CycloneDesignChanges}    \\
    \hline
\makecell{Article}
    & \makecell{Target\\ Part} 
        & \makecell{Design\\ Modification}
            & \makecell{X Range\\ (\si{\micro\metre})}
                & \makecell{Summary of\\ Findings}    \\
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Various research efforts to improve the design of Mixing tank (cont.)} \\
    \hline
\makecell{Article}
    & \makecell{Target\\ Part}
        & \makecell{Design\\ Modification}
            & \makecell{X Range\\ (\si{\micro\metre})}
                & \makecell{Summary of\\ Findings}    \\
\endhead
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\endfoot\endlastfoot
% table body
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Design changes on a mixing tank to function as a Particle Separator ($D_{50}\leq \qty{3}{\micro\metre}$)}\\ 
    \hline
Arjun Kumar Pukkella (2018)
    & Inlet section 
        & Baffle Plate design 
            & 0.45-0.75
                & Controlled the cut point by adjusting the guide plate location to alter the inlet clearance.  \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{yoshida2005} (2005) \cite{yoshida2005}
    & Inlet section 
        & Secondary injection flow
            & 0.7-1.25 
                & The secondary injection flow should be in the proximity of upper plate and the injection velocity should be a maximum. High tangential velocities are reported in the region close to the secondary injection flow.   \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
                & 1.1-1.75 
                    & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013}(2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        &  Compressed air injection. Secondary flow 
            & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75 & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone. \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
             & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        &  Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\citeauthor{HIRAIWA2013} (2013) \cite{HIRAIWA2013}
    & Inlet section  
        & Compressed air injection. Secondary flow
            & 1.1-1.75 
                & It was observed that the tangential and axial velocities are higher in the upper cylindrical part with the free air inflow cyclone than that without the free air inflow cyclone.    \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

The first page is:

[image]

and  the last page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is with the doublespacing command in my code. When I removed it the problem was solved. Thanks everyone who have tried to help.